# What's the difference between 'address' and 'address payable'?

Tags: solidity, addresses, payable, data-types, type-casting

I saw a Solidity smart contract where some variables were declared with the type `address` and some were declared with the type `address payable`. What are the differences between the two?

- Do they store the same data?
- How do you convert a value from one address type to the other type?

Answer (score 73):

### Data storage and representation in the EVM

The `address` and `address payable` types both store a 160-bit Ethereum address. The concept of payable and non-payable addresses only exists in the Solidity type system at compile-time. The difference between payable and non-payable addresses is gone in the compiled contract code.

---

### Built-in methods

You can use `.transfer(..)` and `.send(..)` on `address payable`, but not on `address`.

You can use a low-level `.call{value: ..}(..)` on both `address` and `address payable`, even if you attach value.

---

### Casting from `address payable` to `address`

`address payable` can be implicitly or explicitly cast to `address`:

```
address payable addr1 = payable(msg.sender);
address addr2 = addr1; // This is correct
address addr3 = address(addr1); // This is correct
```

---

### Casting from `address` to `address payable`

`address` can only be explicitly cast to `address payable`:

```
address addr1 = msg.sender;
address payable addr2 = addr1; // Incorrect
address payable addr3 = payable(addr1); // Correct since Solidity >= 0.6.0
address payable addr4 = address(uint160(addr1)); // Incorrect since Solidity >= 0.8.0
```

---

### Casting `address[]` or `address payable[]`

Although a single `address payable` can be cast to `address`, arrays of one address type cannot be cast to arrays of another address type:

```
function testCast(address payable[] memory _addresses) returns (address[] memory)
{
    return _addresses; // Type error!
}
```

---

### Rationale

Types in programming languages exist for two reasons:

- To provide special type-specific semantics (e.g. `+` on numbers is addition, but `+` on strings might be concatenation)
- To limit the amount of incorrect programs that are accepted by the compiler

The splitting of addresses into `address` and `address payable` serves the latter purpose. It forces the smart contract programmer to think about whether an address should ever receive ether from the smart contract. If it should never receive Ether, the `address` type can be used. Compilation will fail with a type error if the programmer makes a mistake and tries to transfer Ether to that address.

---

### Built-in address constants

`msg.sender` is an `address`

`tx.origin` is an `address`

`block.coinbase` is an `address payable`

Comment: I would ad that type `address payable` was added in Solidity 0.5.0, and prior to this release, `address` type worked as `address payable`.

Comment: Note: Since Solidity 0.6.0, you can cast to `address payable` like this: `payable(...)`

Comment: Note: Since Solidity 0.8.0, address literals such as `address(0x8aB27....)` have the type `address` instead of `address payable`

Comment: Also, since Solidity 0.8.0, change `msg.sender.transfer(x)` to `payable(msg.sender).transfer(x)`. Source: https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.2/080-breaking-changes.html#how-to-update-your-code

Comment: i don't get it `address payable addr4 = payable(addr1);`. why should i state payable on the variable and also cast the address itself to a payable address. what is the purpose of setting the variable as payble if the second one is what adds the functionality of transfer and send. thanks

Comment: `.transfer()` and `.send()` are basically deprecated now, with `.call{value: X}()` being the new recommended way to send X ETH wei to a recipient. Therefore, since `.call` works with both `address` and `address payable`, I assume this means that `address payable` is more or less useless at this point?

Answer (score 14):

Yes, they store the same data, that is a valid ethereum address.

The difference is that the compiler (at compile time) when encounter an “address payable” is ready to allow (if required in the following code) that address to access primitives useful to manage ethers (namely call, transfer, send).

In that sense, after a declaration like:

```
address payable spender;
```

the compiler shall accept any

```
spender.send();
spender.transfer();               (1)
spender.call();
```

and generates the bytecode required to implement them.

On the other hand if the declaration is:

```
address spender;
```

the compiler shall generate error if any of the (1) is encountered.

After the compile time there is not difference between payable or not address. In particular they have the same size in memory and are not distinguishable.

In short it is a congruency tag, nothing more.

Understanding this, it is very simple to convert any **address payable** to **address** and viceversa using cast:

```
address payable spender = msg.sender;
address owner;
address payable newspender;

owner = address(spender);   // this is no more payable
newspender = address( uint160(owner) );    // this is again payable
```

> As you can see to do the opposite (not payable to payable) it is required explicitly to use uint160 as intermediate casting

**Added after 0.6.0 solidity update:**

> now you have the possibility to directly cast any address to a payable address using the “payable” keyword:

```
address payable spender = msg.sender;
address owner;
address payable newspender;

owner = address(spender);   // this is no more payable
newspender = payable(owner);    // this is again payable
```

Comment: Hello, checking if (payable address == address) is always giving me false, even if the addresses are equals... Are they supposed to be checked differently?

Comment: Cast the payable address to a non-payable address format before to check it.If (address (<payableAddressHere>) = <non-payable-address-here>) then…

Answer (score 2):

I was confused about the payable address but after a lot of searching, I find the best use case of a payable address.
when you are working with a solidity smart contract then you use the payable function which receives ethers and stores it in your contract, not your personal address.
so if you want to directly send ethers from the contract to your address then you must need to make your address payable.

Example:

```
address payable contractDeployer;

function recieveEth()public payable{

require(msg.value>0, "amount should be greater then Zero");

// now you directly transfer msg.value to "contractDeployer" account by using builtin function "transfer"

payable(contractDeployer).transfer(msg.value);

}
```

I hope this answer will be useful for you guys.

Thanks