# TypeError: Type address is not implicitly convertible to expected type address payable

Tags: solidity

I'm taking the course from lynda.com "Ethereum: Building Blockchain Decentralized Apps (DApps)" but there's an issue with the contract we're given, and it won't compile:

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;

contract ApprovalContract {
    address payable public sender;
    address payable public receiver;
    address public constant approver = 0x3999BA5D247c800E5Ef3d4de66618741E3675379 ;

function deposit(address _receiver) external payable {

    require (msg.value > 0);
    sender = msg.sender;
    receiver = _receiver;   
    }

function viewApprover () external pure returns(address) {
    return(approver);
    }

function approve() external {
        require(msg.sender == approver);
        receiver.transfer(address(this).balance);
        
    }
}
```

Here the picture from the result of trying to compile the solidity contract:

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Should be

```
function deposit(address payable _receiver) external payable {
```

From [Solidity documentation](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.5.0/types.html#address):

> The address type comes in two flavours, which are largely identical:
>
> address: Holds a 20 byte value (size of an Ethereum address).
>
> address payable: Same as address, but with the additional members transfer and send.
>
> The idea behind this distinction is that address payable is an address you can send Ether to, while a plain address cannot be sent Ether.

Since `address` has fewer methods than `address payable`, you cannot directly assign `address` value to `address payable` variable, though you may explicitly cast `address` to `address payable` (not needed in your case).

Comment: It's works, OMG, it took me 4h for this

Comment: How would you cast `address` to `address payable`?

Comment: cast `address` to `address payable` using ```payable(msg.sender)```

Comment: @NYCTechEngineer this [answer](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/64109/24693) helps too.

Answer (score 11):

This casting worked for me:

> casted "address" to "address payable" with "payable(msg.sender)".