# ParserError: Expected primary expression - address payable - payable()

Tags: solidity, blockchain, ether, payable, type-casting

I'm trying to get myself familiarized with ethereum. So I was going through a repo, and tried to rum the code :

```
function transferFundOnResolve(uint cid) private {
        // Could also be used: complainMap[cid]._status == Status.Resolved && 
        if(complainMap[cid]._reward > 0) {
            if(policeAccounts[complainSolver[cid]] != true) {
                complainSolver[cid].transfer( complainMap[cid]._reward );
                complainMap[cid]._reward = 0;
            }
            else {
                for(uint i=0; i<complainMap[cid]._contributors.length; i++) {
                    complainMap[cid]._contributors[i].transfer( complainMap[cid]._contAmount[i] );
                }
                complainMap[cid]._reward = 0;

            }
        }
    }
```

As it says *TypeError: "send" and "transfer" are only available for objects of type "address payable", not "address".*

So I modified and added **payable()** like :

```
function transferFundOnResolve(uint cid) private {
        // Could also be used: complainMap[cid]._status == Status.Resolved && 
        if(complainMap[cid]._reward > 0) {
            if(policeAccounts[complainSolver[cid]] != true) {
                complainSolver[cid].transfer( payable(complainMap[cid]._reward) );
                complainMap[cid]._reward = 0;
            }
            else {
                for(uint i=0; i<complainMap[cid]._contributors.length; i++) {
                    complainMap[cid]._contributors[i].transfer( payable(complainMap[cid]._contAmount[i]) );
                }
                complainMap[cid]._reward = 0;

            }
        }
    }
```

Now it says : **ParserError: Expected primary expression.**

*How should I resolve this ?*

I have *pragma solidity ^0.5.16;*

Comment: Please add the code where you declared variables. (Like complainMap and contributors)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you got that error because there is no function name payable that take an integer value and return payable address. The parser doesn't recognise it and give you an error like that.

I don't know your complainMap struct but i can guess that in it contain contrivutor variable and it's type is address. In solidity version greater than 0.5.0 they add payable address (you can see more at here: [What's the difference between 'address' and 'address payable'?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/64108/whats-the-difference-between-address-and-address-payable)). The transfer function can only be use on address payable not address so the solution is to change the variable type of contributor from address to address payable or cast it to address payable.

Comment: Can you please tell me, how to cast from address to address payable ?? And updating the question with my structure soon

Comment: I found here : https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/64109/61100, that I can use payable like this

Comment: @Maifee UI Asad To convert from address to address payable you need payable function which can only be use in solidity 0.6.0 and up. But you are using solidity 0.5.18, that mean it is impossible to convert from address to address payable. So the only way is to change variable address to address payable

Comment: hey @haxerl can you show some example code on how casting to address payable worked for you. Ive tried casting to address payable and still getting the same error. To reproduce error: do truffle test on https://github.com/iansamz/Simple-Bank-Solidity.git

Answer (score 1):

Add this in your truffle-config.js

solc version: 0.6.0 and up will support payable(address)

```
module.exports = {
  // See <http://truffleframework.com/docs/advanced/configuration>
  // to customize your Truffle configuration!
  networks: {
    development: {
      host: "localhost",
      port: 7545,
      network_id: "5777",
      gas: 4600000
    }
  },
  compilers: {
    solc: {
      version: "0.6.0",    // Fetch exact version from solc-bin (default: truffle's version)
    }
  },
};
```

In your contract .sol use:
`pragma solidity ^0.6.0;`