# address payable error

Tags: solidity, smart-contract-wallets, ethereumj

please i'm having this issue while trying to deploy my smart contract, please can anyone explain this error for me and how i can solve it

Type address is not implicitly convertible to expected type address payable.
--> gvbs.sol:153:9:
|
153 | address payable investor2 = 0x4B20993Bc481177ec7E8f571ceCaE8A9e22C02db;

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest reading this topic to learn more about casting an address to an address payable [What's the difference between 'address' and 'address payable'?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/64108/whats-the-difference-between-address-and-address-payable)