# Error: Address must be type "payable"

Tags: solidity, remix, error

The code is from [freecodecamp.org](https://freecodecamp.org), and a solidity tutorial from Youtube and theirs worked, but unfortunately mine throws this error:

> Address must be type "payable"

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity >=0.6.6 <0.9.0;

import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/interfaces/AggregatorV3Interface.sol";

contract FundMe {
    
    
    mapping(address => uint256) public addressToAmountFunded;
    address public owner;
    
    constructor() {
        owner = msg.sender;
    }

    function fund() public payable {
        uint256 minimumUSD = 50 * 10 ** 18;//=Gwei
        require(getConversionRate(msg.value) >= minimumUSD,"You need to send more Eth");
        addressToAmountFunded[msg.sender] += msg.value;
    }

    function getVersion() public view returns (uint256){
        AggregatorV3Interface priceFeed = AggregatorV3Interface(0xD4a33860578De61DBAbDc8BFdb98FD742fA7028e);
        return priceFeed.version();
    }

   
    function getPrice() public view returns (uint256){
        AggregatorV3Interface priceFeed = AggregatorV3Interface(0xD4a33860578De61DBAbDc8BFdb98FD742fA7028e);
        (,int256 answer,,,)=priceFeed.latestRoundData();
        return uint256(answer * 10000000000);
    }

    //10000000000 = Gwei which is why we added 10 zeros to getPrice(answer) to convert it to Wei amount
    function getConversionRate(uint256 ethAmount) public view returns (uint256){
        uint256 ethPrice = getPrice();
        uint256 ethAmountInUsd = (ethPrice * ethAmount)/ 1000000000000000000; //divide 2x because we added 10*((getPrice)answer))
        return ethAmountInUsd;
    }
    
    modifier onlyOwner {
        require(msg.sender == owner);
        _;
    }
    
    function withdraw() payable public {
        msg.sender.transfer( address (this).balance);

        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use `.transfer()` or `.send()` on an address it must be an `address payable`. See [this](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/64108/whats-the-difference-between-address-and-address-payable) for more detailed information.

Those two methods are now discouraged because they have an hard coded gas amount of 2300, use `.call{value: address(this).balance}("")`, which does not require the address to be payable, instead.

More info [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/19341/address-send-vs-address-transfer-best-practice-usage) and [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/78124/is-transfer-still-safe-after-the-istanbul-update).

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I tried:    function withdraw() public {
        msg.sender.call{value: address(this).balance}("");
    } and got back from solidity:
Warning: Return value of low-level calls not used.
  --> contracts/Fundme2.sol:44:9:
   |
44 |         msg.sender.call{value: address(this).balance}("");
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

Comment: Try this `(bool success,) = msg.sender.call{value: address(this).balance}("")`